# Can I Batch Update protected properties and classes using Entity Framework Plus?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-plus

Is there any way to do batch updates using Entity Framework Plus (and EF6) on protected (or even private) properties?

For example, say we have a `Planet` entity:

```
public class Planet
{
    protected Planet() { }
    public string Status { get; protected set; }
}
```

I would like to run something like this (as documented [here](https://entityframework-plus.net/batch-update)) :

```
respository
    .Query<Planet>()
    .Where(x => x.Status == "LAME")
    .Update(x => new Planet { Status = "AWESOME" });
```

... but I can't because `Planet` and `Status` are inaccessible to their protection level.

Is there any way to perform a bulk update without making those fields public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](https://entityframework-plus.net/)

No, there is currently no way of doing it.

However, we plan to eventually support dictionary (PropertyName, Value). It's something that could work for you?

If yes, I recommend you to post this request on our Issue Tracker and reference this SO question on it: https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/issues

*(It will be easier for us to follow the issue on GitHub since SO is not done for this)*

Comment: I think that would _probably_ help! I'll add it to the issue tracker: https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/issues/533